# If $b_n$ is a non-negative sequence and the limit is 0, then the limit of $\sqrt{b_n}$ is 0.

Tags: calculus, analysis, proof-verification

My proof so far is as follows:

Choose $\epsilon > 0$. Since the limit of $b_n$ is 0, $|b_n - 0| = |b_n| = b_n < \epsilon$.

I'm not sure how to proceed here. I'm thinking of showing $b_n < \epsilon^2$, and from there claiming $\sqrt{b_n} < \epsilon$. I don't thinking this is right however, as if $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, $\epsilon^2 < \epsilon$ and so $b_n < \epsilon^2$ does not follow.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\epsilon\in(0,1)$, consider the positive number $\epsilon^{2}$, then there is some $N$ such that $|b_{n}|<\epsilon^{2}$ for all $n\geq N$, then $\sqrt{b_{n}}<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea. Since $b_n \to 0$, there exists $N>0$ such that for all $n\ge N$, $b_n < \epsilon^2$. Then $$\sqrt{b_n} < \sqrt{\epsilon^2} = \epsilon$$

Comment: I'm confused on why we can claim $b_n < \epsilon^2$. From my understanding, this claim comes from the fact $b_n < \epsilon < \epsilon^2$. But say $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$; in this case, $\epsilon > \epsilon^2$, so we can't really say $b_n < \epsilon^2$. Would I have to add the stipulation "For $\epsilon \geq 1 ...$" and then proceed with the claim $b_n < \epsilon^2$?

Comment: If a (positive) sequence $b_n$ converges to $0$, then for any error term $\epsilon>0$ I pick, there must be some step $N$ in the sequence such that all terms beyond it, $b_n$, must be at most $\epsilon$ away from 0. Convergence means this definition works for any error $\epsilon$ I pick. So if I pick, say $\epsilon^2$, then I can find some step $N$ where $b_n< \epsilon^2$ for all $n \ge N$. This new step $N$ may be larger or smaller than my original $N$, but I don't care about that.